# jQuery - Call function in function with dynamic content (.load())

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site in which content is dynamic loaded via `jQuery .load()`. Sadly, I can't catch an event from the dynamic loaded content even though using `.on()`.

This is my function in which I can't trigger the `$("#control_right").on('click')`-function after loading `changeContent(2)`:

```
function changeContent(step){
$('#content').toggle(100);
setTimeout(function() {
      $('#content').load("template/step_" + step + ".html");
}, 180);
$('#content').delay(300).toggle(200).queue(function(){

    if(step === 1){ // IF STEP 1. CHOOSE MALE OR FEMALE
        console.log("step1");
        $("#choice_man").on('click', function(){
            changeContent(2);
        });

        $("#choice_woman").on('click', function(){
            changeContent(2);
        });
    }

    if(step === 2){ // IF STEP 2. Do something else
        $("#control_right").on('click', function() {
            console.log("CLICK");
        });
    }
});
}
```

I hope my problem is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing selector to one from DOM elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '#control_right', function(){...})
```

**Bdw**, why are you using `.delay(300).toggle(200)`?

```
.load('url.html #loadContentFrom', function(){/* Callback function */})
```

Answer (score 1):

like many other answer in stackoverflow (please search before posting your question), you have to  use `on` delegated event and not just `on()`.

```
 $('#content').on('click', "#choice_man",function(){
       ...
```

**delegating it to your closest static parent present in the document at the time of insertion**  is preferred rather than document itself performancewise